# What is a safe way to join strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, join

I need to construct a path to a file from two strings. I could use this (not tested, though):

```
/* DON'T USE THIS CODE! */
/* cmp means component */
char *path_cmp1 = "/Users/john/";
char *path_cmp2 = "foo/bar.txt";
unsigned len = strlen(path_cmp1);
char *path = path_cmp1;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(path_cmp2); i++) {
  path[len + i] = path_cmp2[i];
}
```

but this could lead to memory corruption I guess. Is there a better way to do this, or is there a function for this in the standard library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *join(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    char* result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);

    if (result) // thanks @pmg
    {
        strcpy(result, s1);
        strcat(result, s2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is simple enough to be written in place, especially when you have multiple strings to concatenate.

Note that these functions return their destination argument, so you can write

```
char* result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
assert(result);
strcat(strcpy(result, s1), s2);
```

but this is less readable.

Comment: +1 ... but `if (result) { strcpy; strcat; }` and automagically return NULL if malloc fails

Comment: By "written in place", do you mean `join(join("foo", "bar"), "baz")`? That would leak to a helluva memory leak. Your second example isn't only ugly, but unsafe due to lack of error checking.

Comment: @pmg I always check for `NULL` when using malloc.

Comment: @larsman: no, I mean writing the malloc, strcpy and strcat entirely instead of the join function.

Comment: This code scans s1 3 times for and s2 twice to just find out their lengths. If you want it faster you only need to scan each of them once.

Comment: @eznme: this is clear code which works. After profiling, this can indeed be optimized. I prefer this than hunting off-by-one errors.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I am fuzzy about strings; doesn't this malloc need to be freed somewhere (outside the scope of the join function) ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. perhaps it's a vital update in your answer then. I can 'see' many newbies using the function as is and forgetting to free the malloc completely.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

char *a = "hello ";
char *b = "goodbye";
char *joined;

asprintf(&joined, "%s%s", a, b)
```

Comment: Non-standard, but not too hard to implement in terms of `snprintf`. +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *path_cmp1 = "/Users/john/";
char *path_cmp2 = "foo/bar.txt";

int firstLength = strlen(path_cmp1);
int secondLength = strlen(path_cmp2);
char *both = malloc(firstLength+secondLength+1);
memcpy(both, path_cmp1, firstLength);
memcpy(both+firstLength, path_cmp2, secondLength+1);
       // this +1 copyes the second string's null-terminator too.
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems in this code:
1 - calling strlen on the for loop is a bad idea, it will calculate the string length every iteration, so it is better to call it once before the loop and keep the result in a variable.

2 - The same strlen problem applies to strlen(path_cmp1) inside the loop, call it before the loop and increments its size.

In the end, it is better to simple copy both strings and store those on a dynamic allocated string, like:

```
char *join_strings(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    size_t lens1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t lens2 = strlen(s2);

    //plus 1 for \0
    char *result = malloc(lens1 + lens2 + 1);

    if(result)
    {
        memcpy(result, s1, lens1);
        memcpy(result+lens1, s2, lens2+1);
    }

    //do not forget to call free when do not need it anymore
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a performance penalty in writing "clear" code :)

Comment: Recommend `if(result) { }` around the two `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 3):

There are `strcat` and `strncat` for that.

Answer (score 2):

create a new string with the length of both inputs and strcpy/strcat the inputs and don't forget the null terminator.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strcat`. (You are right that your code will lead to memory corruption.)

Answer (score 2):

How about `strcat` in string.h?

Answer (score 2):

`path` is just a pointer to `path_cmp1` and you are trying to access beyond the end of the array. Very occasionally this will work, but in the vast majority of cases you will cause memory corruption.

As others have pointed out use `strcat` to concatenate strings.